# Right-align button with dynamic text

Tags: android, android-layout

In my user interface, I have a fragment with a RelativeLayout. At the bottom of this RelativeLayout, I have two buttons: one should be on the left, the other on the right, with empty space between them. The left one has static text (but because the app will be translated, I don't know what width it will be). The text in the right one can change arbitrarily.

Since I already have a RelativeLayout, I started out trying to lay them out inside the RelativeLayout like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/left" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/right" />
```

But this has the problem that if the text in the right-hand button is too long, it will overlap the left-hand button.

I next tried to constrain the left-hand edge of the right-hand button by adding `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_left"`, but with this, the right-hand button would always fill the available width. When the text in the right-hand button is short, I want it to shrink to leave a gap between it and the left-hand button.

I next tried to use a LinearLayout, so I could set layout_gravity on the buttons, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pass"
        android:text="@string/right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Still no joy. I expected this to work, but the right-hand button stays just to the right of the left-hand button, instead of sticking to the right edge of the screen. I can see in the layout editor that the LinearLayout correctly fills the width of the screen, but the button stubbornly stays next to its friend.

I tried adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to the right-hand button too, but again, that made it always expand to fill the available space.

Next, I tried to add an empty View between the buttons, to expand and force the right button to the right, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/left" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This works fine when the text is short, just like my original RelativeLayout did, but now when the text on the right-hand button is long, its width is limited by the width of the screen, not the available space, so it extends off the right-hand edge of the screen. Again, I can see in the layout editor that the LinearLayout has the correct width, but the button is extending ourside its parent's bounds. This happens even if the button has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Oddly enough, increasing the layout_gravity on the right-hand button makes it smaller until it fits inside the available space, but of course that also makes it fill the space when the text is small.

I can't believe it's this hard to get this right. I've seen half a dozen similar questions on SO, but they all have easy workarounds. If the button text is fixed, you can set the margin to a fixed width by hand. If the expanding widget is a TextView instead of a Button, you can just let it expand and use `android:gravity` to move the text inside the widget, but you can't do that with a button because the background and borders are visible on the screen.

Comment: If i understand correctly, I would have a linearlayout with 2 buttons of wrap_content width, and the dynamic one with a weight of 1

Comment: or use a minWidth param with the last solution you tried

Comment: @njzk2 weight 1 would make it always take up all the spare width. I want it to be less wide than that if the text is short: that is, the width should be the *minimum* out of the available width and the text width.

Comment: problem here is : if your dynamic text is very long, what amount of space can you give the static text ?

Comment: It has to always show the static text on the left button (which is only short). I can handle long dynamic text with ellipsize, or wrapping onto two lines, but it absolutely can't overlap the other button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that adding the LinearLayout was the wrong approach. Using `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_left" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` works fine with a TextView, because that can soak up the available space without changing its appearance. Instead of trying to change the layout, I just need to use something that can expand to fill the available space and contain the Button: a FrameLayout. Here's the working code, which still goes inside my root RelativeLayout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/left" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_left" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Turn_button_pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/right" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, the FrameLayout always takes up all the space to the right of the left-hand button, and lays out the right-hand button inside that space using `android:layout_gravity="right"`.

This answer only adds one extra layout, but if someone has a way to do it only using the existing RelativeLayout, to minimise the number of ViewGroups in the layout, I'll accept that as a solution.

Comment: I started to think of something like that, then saw that you found it out already (and quite a while ago, too). I don't see any better solution, for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a TextView and make it look like a button. Create a dummy button, extract the background and set that background to the textfield programmatically.
(Not tested but should give it the apperance of a button)

```
Drawable d = button1.getBackground();
textView1.setBackground(d);
```

then you just set the onClickListener and that should yield what you're looking for. The TextView would take the place of the "button_right" in your first layout.

**Edit

Your xml would look something like this

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button_left"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="@string/left" /> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/button_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"     
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:maxEms="10"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Alas, a TextView with a background and click listener has exactly the same problem as a Button: it always (visually) takes all the available space. The only reason a TextView is usually simpler is that the user can't see how much space it takes up.

Comment: Well if you add the textField and set the maxEms property to 10 then it will take up to at most half the screen and if the height and width are wrap content then it will expand and shrink when the text is changed.

Comment: Yes, that would be a great solution, if I knew how wide the max button width should be. But I have to support different orientations and screen sizes, so `maxEms="10"` wouldn't always give me the right width.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can live with the constraint, that the right button only can take up to up half of the available space, this could be a solution for you:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A short text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="A very long text which is limited to one half of the available space" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```